# Is there a good resource of css snippets?

Tags: css

Usually when you design a website you don't want to take apart a complete css or fiddle around with the basic css buldingblogs.

Is there a good resource of basic building blocks for css. Something like different Menus, Page effects, and basic layouts that is written in clean code and can be easily combined together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://snipplr.com/popular/language/css

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/development/useful-css-snippets/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/

These sites I find helpful when I am trying to find css snippets.  Should be well over 500 snippets there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/css/

http://www.alistapart.com/

... and many more.